# Read pom.xml from Pipeline A to Pipeline B in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have two Jenkins Pipeline, say Pipeline A and Pipeline B. Here, Pipeline B is the subset of Pipeline A i.e. first Pipeline A will run then it will invoke Pipeline B.

Pipeline A is building the maven project using pom.xml.
Pipeline B will then get invoked, which will deploy the .war of maven project to artifactory.

I want to read the pom.xml in Pipeline B which will be passed as parameter from Pipeline A.

Can anyone help me with the way **how we can read the pom.xml in Pipeline B**?

Note: I am using declarative pipeline code.

Comment: What is the reason that you have two separate pipelines?

Comment: @JF Meier Reason being I need another pipeline that will deploy the artifacts to artifactory. I want to have separate pipeline that will do the job of deploying the artifacts rather than doing it in one job where we build the project and then deploy the artifacts.

Comment: Ok, but why? What is the advantage?

Comment: Whenever any developer runs his build pipeline irrespective of any project, this artifactory pipeline he/she should invoke to deploy artifacts.

Comment: Sounds wrong to me.. let the build run and deploy it's built artifacts to the appropriate repository manager ...I don't any advantage about this approach or you haven't have it explained not detailed enough..

Comment: @sourav19 This sounds more like you should use Jenkins library functions. If you want to reuse a given deployment method, instead of putting it into a separate pipeline, you can just write a library function and use it in all the builds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to archive your file `pom.xml` in the pipeline A (with step [archiveArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/)). And then copy this archived file from pipeline A into your pipeline B (using [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/)).

Something like this :

- Pipeline A :

```
    stage('Archive pom.xml'){
        steps {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'pom.xml'
        }
    }
```

- Pipeline B :

```
    stage('Get pom.xml'){
        steps {
            copyArtifacts projectName: 'pipeline-A', filter: 'pom.xml'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer I believe would be to use an artifact repository manager to store the pom from the pipeline A, which you grab from the artifact repository manager during the pipeline B execution.